# Creating a string named file in a specific directory

Tags: c++, database, string

I just got into programming and was doing a fun little exercise in c++ ( a login app using .dat's as a database ) and ran into a problem. Is there any way to create a "string named file" in a specific directory?  I've seen that ones can create both a string named file and a file in a specific directory but cant seem to find the answer for this question. Once again sorry if this has already been gone over and thank you.

This is the part I was on about I'll put the full code down below to get some more opinions as well, just do take in mind that I'm a beginner and the code isn't finished.

```
int DataBase() {

    ofstream DBName(( /*Potencially my directory? + */ BaseAccount + ".dat").c_str());      
    DBName << Pass << endl;

}
```

My full code will be down here, im fully open to new suggestions, yet, I do already have some parts of the code that I want to keep them as it is, again do remember that I'm a starter and thank you for your attention!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

    int UserVar;    
    string Account, Pass, AccountLog;
    int main(), login();

int DataBase() {
    
    ofstream DBName(( /*Potencially my directory? + */ BaseAccount + ".dat").c_str());      
    DBName << Pass << endl;

}

void wait(int seconds){
    clock_t endwait;
    endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
    while (clock() < endwait) {}
}

void DataBaseCheck(string AccCheck){
    ifstream DBLookForAcc(AccCheck.c_str());
    
    cout<<"Looking for the user in the data base..."<<endl;
    wait(2);
    system("cls");
    
    string AccData, AccPass, DBPass;
    
    int DBVarTries=3;
    
    if (DBLookForAcc){
        cout<<"Account Found!"<<endl;
        wait(1);
        system("cls");
            ifstream AccData;
            AccData.open(AccCheck);
            AccData>>DBPass;
            do{
                cout<<"Please enter your password: ";
                cin>>AccPass;
                
                if(AccPass==DBPass){
                    system("cls");
                    cout<<"You sucessfully logged in!"<<endl;
                    exit(0);
                }
                
                else (AccPass==DBPass);{
                    DBVarTries=DBVarTries-1;
                    system("cls");
                    cout<<"The password is wrong, please try again!"<<endl<<endl<<DBVarTries<<" attempts remaining. ";
                    wait(2);
                    system("cls");
                    continue;
                }
            }
            while(DBVarTries!=0);
    }
    else {
        system("cls");
        cout<<"Sorry... We couldnt find your account."<<endl;
        wait(1);
        login();
    }
}
        
int login(){
    
    system("cls");
    
    cout<<"Sign in"<<endl<<endl<<endl<<"User Name: " ;
    cin>>AccountLog;
    system("cls");
    DataBaseCheck((AccountLog + ".dat").c_str());
}
        
int main(){

        do{         
            
        system("cls");
        
        cout<<"Sign up"<<endl<<endl<<endl<<"Insert your user: ";
        cin>>Account;
            if(Account=="1"){
                do{
                    login();
                }
                while(true);
            }
                
        cout<<"Insert your accounts password: ";
        cin>>Pass;
            if(Pass=="1"){
                do{
                login();
                }
                while(true);
            }
        
        system("cls");
        DataBase();
        cout<<"The account was saved to the Data Base. ";
        wait(2);
        system("cls");
                
            UserVar=UserVar+1;                  
        }
        while(UserVar=4);
        cout<<"You cant sign any more users up."<<endl<<endl<< "Login protocol" ;
        
    login();
}
```

Comment: If the directory is stored in a variable, `MyDirectory + "/" + BaseAccount + ".dat"`.

Comment: Nikita, would that be something like this: 

        `string MyDir="C:\\Users\\Desktop\\C++\\Menu\\Accounts\\Main\\Data Base";
 ofstream DBName((MyDir + "/"+ BaseAccount + ".dat").c_str()); ` 
Bc if so, i still cant get it to work